# I'm having issues setting up ansi-term in emacs

Tags: emacs, zsh, prezto

Note, I use zsh, with a plugin called prezto, which gives a nice zsh configuration structure. When I start *ansi-term* mode, it is unable to render the fonts correctly:

My ansi-terminal looks like:
[image]

My typical terminal looks like:
[image]

I'm wondering if anyone has had similar issues. I'm not an expert on font/character sets to really know where to begin trying to diagnose this issue.

Also, running things like htop causes flickered output and in some cases, no output on some of the rows.

I'm really motivated to have ansi-terminal configured correctly.

Thanks.

Comment: When you say `ansi-terminal`, do you mean `ansi-term`? What does `echo $TERM` print (e.g. `eterm-color`)? Is there a corresponding entry under `/usr/share/terminfo`?

Comment: @rhashimoto thanks! Made the edit.